# How to convert jquery ajax call in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I would like to convert this jquery ajax call to c# code. May I know how to convert?

```js
$.ajax({
 url:  'http://gothere.sg/maps/geo',
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 data:  {
  'output' : 'json',
  'q'  : address,
  'client' : '',
  'sensor' : false
 },
 type: 'GET',
 success: function(data) {
        
 },
 statusCode: {
  404: function() {
   alert('Page not found');
  }
 },
});
```

My C# code return 404. How to specify dataType, data and type in C#.
May I know how to pass these three parameter in C#.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {

            // TODO - Send HTTP requests
            var url = "http://gothere.sg/maps/geo";
            var dataType = "jsonp";
            var type = "GET";

            Console.WriteLine("Making API Call...");
            using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate }))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("data?output=json&q=550238&client=''&sensor=false").Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `callback=` parameter to url. basically you are requesting a `jsonp` resource.

so the url should have callback parameter

```
http://gothere.sg/maps/geo?callback=&output=json&q=dell&client=&sensor=false
```

navigate to this url and you can see result and if you remove callback parameter it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need a trailing slash on your url. Otherwise the request is going to `http://gothere.sg/maps/geodata?output=...` and you get a 404.

So change it to

```
var url = "http://gothere.sg/maps/geo/";
```

Comment: I have tried with trailing slash but still return 404. I can get the data using $.ajax. Thanks

Comment: OK so I just tried the url http://gothere.sg/maps/geo/data?output=json&q=550238&client=''&sensor=false in my browser and got a 404 so that's not a valid url.

Comment: Please look at the ajax code. It is returning the data. The issue is that I don't know how to call it in C#. Thanks.